# Which function in C# like Mid() function in VBA?

Tags: c#, vba

In VBA Access, I get a short string from long string by line below:

```vb
tmpStr1,tmpStr2 as string;  
tmpStr1 = "abcdefgh"  
tmpStr2 = Mid(tmmStr1,3,1) 'result is c
```

How to do same in C#?

Comment: `string.Substring`

Comment: dear Peter Duniho, I don't find the key word "VB to C# Functions " until you read and answer this question, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to do this.

```
var tmpStr1 = "abcdefgh";
var tmpStr2 = tmpStr1.Substring(3, 1);

Console.WriteLine(tmpStr2);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WpDrpk

Answer (score 0):

Use `Substring` in c#

```
string.Substring( int startIndex, int length );
```

you need to do that like this

```
tmpStr2 = Substring(tmmStr1,2,1)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In C# you have `Substring`. To get the same result as in the shown VBA:

```
string tmpStr1 = "abcdefgh";
string tmpStr2 = a.Substring(2, 1);
```

`Substring` takes two arguments 1. start position (starting with 0), 2. count of characters to take.